# Find 2 numbers that multiply to a number and add to another number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code, however, I am unsure whether it is the fastest way to achieve this objective.

```
import random

add_to = int(input("2 numbers must add to: "))
multiply_to = int(input("2 numbers must multiyply to: "))
solved = False

while solved == False:
    nums = random.sample(range(-100, 150), 2)
    if (nums[0] + nums[1] == add_to) and (nums[0] * nums[1] == multiply_to):
        print(nums)
        print('Solved')
        break
```

Question:
1. Is it possible for the range to be set based upon the input of numbers given by the user.

Comment: Using random numbers is one of the **slowest ways** to find the two numbers. The much faster way is to solve two equations, `x1+x2=sum;x1x2=product`, which is not hard.

Answer (score 3):

## Code Review

`while solved == False:` is an awkward way of writing the loop condition.  `while not solved:` would be clearer and more Pythonic.

---

You never set `solved = True` anywhere.  Instead, you unconditionally `break` out of the loop.  This means your loop could actually be written `while True:`, but I don't think this is clearer.  Using `solved = True` instead of `break` would terminate the loop in an expected way.

---

This is verbose:

```
    nums = random.sample(range(-100, 150), 2)
    if (nums[0] + nums[1] == add_to) and (nums[0] * nums[1] == multiply_to):
```

You could unpack `nums` into to individual variables, and avoid the `[0]` and `[1]` indexing operations, for more performant code:

```
    x1, x2 = random.sample(range(-100, 150), 2)
    if x1 + x2 == add_to and x1 * x2 == multiply_to:
```

---

If you give values which can never work with integers, like add to `2` and multiply to `3`, you have an infinite loop.  You should have a "give up after so many attempts" procedure.

---

## Monte Carlo

As pointed out by [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242330/100620), there is an \$O(1)\$ solution to the problem.

However, if your goal is to utilize a [Monte Carlo simulation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) ...

If `multiply_to` is:

- positive, then the numbers must be the same sign, both positive or both negative, which you could determine by looking at the `add_to` sign,
- negative, then one number must be greater than zero, and the other must be less than zero,
- zero, then one number must be zero.

eg)

```
if multiply_to > 0:
    if add_to > 0:
        r1 = range(1, add_to)
        r2 = range(1, add_to)
    else:
        r1 = range(add_to + 1, 0)
        r2 = range(add_to + 1, 0)

elif multiply_to < 0:
    r1 = range(1, 150)   # A positive value in your initial range bracket
    r2 = range(-100, 0)  # A negative value in your initial range bracket

else:
    r1 = range(add_to, add_to + 1)
    r2 = range(0, 1)


for _ in range(10_000):
    x1 = random.choice(r1)
    x2 = random.choice(r2)
    if x1 + x2 == add_to and x1 * x2 == multiply_to:
        print(f"Solved: {x1} + {x2} = {add_to}, {x1} * {x2} = {multiply_to}")
        break
else:
    print("Couldn't find a solution")
```

Comment: Nice answer. I'd prefer `while True` over a flag. But otherwise agree +1.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than generating two random numbers it would be much faster to generate one and determine the other.

$$
\begin{align}
    x + y &= \text{sum}\\
    x * y &= \text{product}
\end{align}
$$

Since \$\text{sum}\$ and \$\text{product}\$ are constants we can determine \$y\$ from either. And go on to find the equation that \$x\$ must hold.

$$
\begin{align}
    x + y &= \text{sum}\\
    y &= \text{sum} - x\\
    x * y &= \text{product}\\
    x * (\text{sum} - x) &= \text{product}\\
    \text{sum}x - x^2 &= \text{product}\\
\end{align}
$$

This means that we can find the solution by only using \$x\$, and determining \$y\$ after the fact.

We can see how this effects your code by using `range` rather than `random.sample`. When generating both \$x\$ and \$y\$ you'll need two `for _ in range(n)` loops, which are nested. This means your code will run in \$O(n^2)\$ time. With only \$x\$ it will however run in \$O(n)\$ time as it will have only one for loop.

However we can get better than \$O(n)\$ time. As you should be able to see that the math is producing a quadratic, and so we can just use the [Quadratic Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

$$
\begin{align}
    \text{sum}x - x^2 &= \text{product}\\
    0 &= x^2 - \text{sum}x + \text{product}\\
    x &= \frac{\text{sum} \pm \sqrt{\text{sum}^2 - 4\text{product}}}{2}\\
    y &= \text{sum} - x
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You goofed your quadratic formula substitution.  "-sum x" means "b = -sum", so the first term "-b" becomes "-(-sum)", which is "+sum", not "-sum".

Comment: @AJNeufeld Indeed I must have misread something without a minus. Thank you :)